# PooledOLS in python

Tags: python-3.x, regression

I have been trying to use panelOLS regression but I kept on getting errors, I have attached the lines of code and the error.
    'mod=PanelOLS(data.FDI,data[['Trade openness','GDP growth']],time_effects=True)'
    ' res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)`
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72sWE.png)

Comment: The error message states that there is a divide-by-zero error. Does any of the data have a zero value?

Comment: some are in zero's and some are negative, I have tried to replace the zero's with a constant but it didn't work

Comment: A quick test is to remove all zero and negative value data points and re-run the regression, for the sole purpose of determining if the error re-occurs.